# Bash: Creating arrays on the fly, but cannot access them later

Tags: arrays, bash, var

I can 'seemingly' successfully create arrays on the fly, but cannot access them afterward, what am I doing wrong?
Please note, I have googled this to death and cannot find a good answer.

Sorry, for this extra verbiage, but the website thinks most of my post is code and insists on extra details....

```
Code:
for i in `seq 1 3`;do
    echo "Attempting to create array$i ... count: '$count'"
    mytempvar=()
    mytempvar=$i
    echo "local mytempvar: '$mytempvar'"
    for j in `seq 1 $i`;do
        eval mytempvar+=($j)
    done
    echo "Printing out contents of array$i: '${mytempvar[@]}''"
    echo "Attempting to print out contents of array$i directly: '${i[@]}''"
done
for i in `seq 1 5`;do
    mytempvar=()
    mytempvar=$i
    echo "local mytempvar: '$mytempvar'"
    echo "Later: Attempting to print out contents of array$i: '${mytempvar[@]}''"
    echo "Later: Attempting to print out contents of array$i directly: '${i[@]}''"
done
```

> ```
> Output:
> ./bash_test_varname_arrays.sh
> Attempting to create array1 ...
> i: '1' mytempvar: '1'
> Printing out contents of array1: '1 1''
> Attempting to print out contents of array1 directly: '1''
> Attempting to create array2 ...
> i: '2' mytempvar: '2'
> Printing out contents of array2: '2 1 2''
> Attempting to print out contents of array2 directly: '2''
> Attempting to create array3 ...
> i: '3' mytempvar: '3'
> Printing out contents of array3: '3 1 2 3''
> Attempting to print out contents of array3 directly: '3''
> i: '1' mytempvar: '1'
> Later: Attempting to print out contents of array1: '1''
> Later: Attempting to print out contents of array1 directly: '1''
> i: '2' mytempvar: '2'
> Later: Attempting to print out contents of array2: '2''
> Later: Attempting to print out contents of array2 directly: '2''
> i: '3' mytempvar: '3'
> Later: Attempting to print out contents of array3: '3''
> Later: Attempting to print out contents of array3 directly: '3''
> i: '4' mytempvar: '4'
> Later: Attempting to print out contents of array4: '4''
> Later: Attempting to print out contents of array4 directly: '4''
> i: '5' mytempvar: '5'
> Later: Attempting to print out contents of array5: '5''
> Later: Attempting to print out contents of array5 directly: '5''
> ```

Comment: You are (re)creating the same array variable `mytempvar` 3 times. `mytempvar=$i` is equivalent to `mytempvar[0]=$i`.

Comment: (Also, your code doesn't match your output.)

Comment: Why do you need `eval` here: `eval mytempvar+=($j)`?

Comment: Every time you do `mytempvar=()` you're clearing out the array. You shouldn't do that inside the loop, you should do it only before the loop that's going to fill in the array.

Comment: I'm assuming the intent was something like `eval array$i+=($j)`.

Comment: bash does not do multidimensional arrays, and dynamic variable names are gross. Are you sure bash is the right tool for this job?

Answer (score 0):

To really create a new array dynamically, you need a variable whose *value* is the name of the array to create. A small example.

```
for i in 1 2 3; do
    name=array$i
    declare -a "$name"
    declare "$name[0]=zero"
    declare "$name[1]=one"
done
# Proof the new variables exist
declare -p array1
declare -p array2
declare -p array3
```

However, in `bash` 4.3, this becomes much easier using namerefs.

```
for i in 1 2 3; do
   declare -n arr=array$i
   arr=(zero one)
done
```

Comment: also, because brace expansion is cooler than `\`seq 1 3\``: `{1..3}` is equivalent.

Comment: There's also a shorthand: `declare -n arr; for arr in array{1..3}; do`

Comment: @BenjaminW., there was in the question, and this answer just has `1 2 3` which isn't a replacement for most real cases

Comment: Simply awesome answer, it is working great for me now!

Comment: @jeremysprofile I don't recommend using either `seq` or `{1..3}`, but a C-style for loop instead: `for ((i=1; i<=3; i++))`. Brace expansion works for simple *hard-coded* sequences, but still expands to the *entire* sequence at once. The C-style loop works with sequences with either bound specified by a variable, and generates each element on demand.